# number format in SQL INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

Hi guys i need some support on number format in SQL INSERT INTO

i need to convert {$data['rank']['points']} as **number format**, so that instead of it showing as 5467389 it converts it to 54,673,89
the data is being imported from API Data

this is my code

```
$host="hostname"; // Host name
$username="database"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="dbname"; // Database name
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


// API Data
$url = "http://api.erpk.org/citizen/profile/3121752.json?key=Yn3AsG80";
$json = $json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(citid, citname, rankpoints)VALUES('{$data['id']}', '{$data['name']}', '{$data['rank']['points']}')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='supplies_insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: why? why paste a number as a string in the database?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  What is the data type of the `rankpoints` column in your table?  You're inserting a value into that column as a character value (since it's wrapped in quotes).

Comment: @luk2302 does have a good point though. You should probably be using `number_format` *after* you pull data *out* of the database rather than when you insert it into the database. That way, it can be stored as an integer or float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `%s` (citid, citname, rankpoints) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
  mysql_real_escape_string($tbl_name),
  $data['id'],
  mysql_real_escape_string($data['name']}),
  mysql_real_escape_string(number_format($data['rank']['points'])));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: thank you this was the soltuion i was looking for and works how i need it to

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's number_format() function if I understand your requirement correctly. Let me know if that's not what you want.

Comment: i need to insert number_format() for {$data['rank']['points']} not view

Comment: I mean if you want to insert it in as a formatted number you can do this in your insert query where you're saving $data['rank']['points']..
number_format($data['rank']['points'])